# How to use DLookup In an Update Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two tables: "PartNumberX" and "MasterPartTable". My end goal is to extract certain fields out of the "MasterPartTable" using queries to get a list of unique part numbers ("MasterPartTable" has duplicates). I was able to successfully get all the fields out that I wanted except for one using the `SELECT DISTINCT` method. The last column, "Part Name" unfortunately is sloppily created (by someone else) and some part names have a comma where an identical part number may not eg. "Assembly, The Thing" and "Assembly The Thing" both have the same part number so I only want one of them. My idea was that I would be able to insert the good data into a table and then run an update query that uses a `DLookup` to look up the part name using the part number in "PartNumberX" to look up the corresponding part name from "MasterPartTable" but I can't seem to get it to work.

When I use the update query below, it returns the same number of blank fields as there are in "PartNumberX".

```
 UPDATE PartNumberX 
 SET PartNumberX.[Part Name] = DLookUp("[MasterPartTable].[Part_Name]","MasterPartTable","MasterPartTable.Part_Number = PartNumberX.Part_Number");
```

Am I missing something here or is there a different way to do this? I know that I could use VBA and scroll through each field individually to do this but I would prefer a much faster query.

Edit-

Using the second method from HansUp I got the following:

`UPDATE MasterpartsTable INNER JOIN PartNumberX ON MasterpartsTable.Part_Number=`
`PartNumberX.Part_Number`
`SET PartNumberX.[Part Name] = [MasterpartsTable].[Part_Name];`

Which results in an empty query.

Edit2-

I actually just ran the darn thing and it worked perfectly! I don't understand why the preview comes up empty, but regardless it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DLookup` criteria option ...

```sql
"MasterPartTable.Part_Number = PartNumberX.Part_Number"
```

... references the name of a field (`PartNumberX.Part_Number`).  You need the field's value there instead of its name.

Use a `SELECT` query to work out the logic and syntax.  After you have that returning the correct data, you can adapt as an `UPDATE` query.

If `Part_Number` is a numeric datatype ...

```sql
SELECT
    [Part Name],
    Part_Number,
    DLookUp(
        "Part_Name",
        "MasterPartTable",
        "Part_Number = " & Part_Number
    ) AS master_part_name
FROM PartNumberX;
```

If `Part_Number` is text datatype, include quotes ...

```sql
"Part_Number = '" & Part_Number & "'"
```

However, I suspect you could avoid `DLookup` by joining those two tables.  If this `SELECT` query aligns the data correctly, convert it to an `UPDATE`:

```sql
SELECT
    p.[Part Name],
    p.Part_Number,
    m.Part_Number,
    m.Part_Name
FROM
    PartNumberX AS p
    INNER JOIN MasterPartTable AS m
    ON p.Part_Number = m.Part_Number;
```

An `UPDATE` based on `INNER JOIN` could be noticeably faster than the `DLookup` version, especially if the join field (`Part_Number`) is indexed.